# Either|Or part of regex for matching two possibilities

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-alternation

We have two ways of referring to the same system:

- tr12345
- fr12345

Right now I have one regular expression per variation, e.g

1. `/(?:^|^\s|[^\/a-zA-Z0-9])tr([0-9]+).*$/img`
2. `/(?:^|^\s|[^\/a-zA-Z0-9])fr([0-9]+).*$/img`

This works fine, but I thought it could be more efficient by combining the two. I saw from other articles that you can use the alternation `|` to match variations. Do I need to repeat the regex after the "tr" if I'm trying to match both?
E.g is something like this possible?

```
/(?:^|^\s|[^\/a-zA-Z0-9])tr|fr([0-9]+).*$/img
```

Example input1:

> tr12345

Desired output1:

> 12345

Example input2:

> fr123456

Desired output2:

> 123456

I've been playing with it here:
https://regex101.com/r/FUCmv0/2

Comment: Try [`s.replace(/\b[tf]r\s?([0-9]+)/ig, '$1')`](https://regex101.com/r/mAIf0S/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do it in a wrong way. '|' is actually OR, and have low priority, so your regex is ...tr OR fr..., but you need ...(tr|fr)...

So you should use () (like in math expressions). And regex will be

```
/(?:^|^\s|[^\/a-zA-Z0-9])(tr|fr)([0-9]+).*$/img
```

Note that () also produces match groups.

But in your case next expression will be better:

```
/(?:^|^\s|[^\/a-zA-Z0-9])[tf]r([0-9]+).*$/img
```

Here `[tf]` means "one of [t,r]"

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Although what would happen in scenarios where there's a variation more than one letter? E.g tr12345 & kn12345? The square brackets only match single characters, right? Or can I group two characters into OR expressions? I might be overcomplicating...

Comment: @Tiago , OR works fine in this case. For example, /ab(aca|cde)ba/ will match both abacaba & abcdeba with match groups 'aca' or 'cde'

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working, including making this a non-capturing group: `/(?:^|^\s|[^\/a-zA-Z0-9])(?:tr|fr)([0-9]+).*$/img`